# VB.net send hex code with unwanted "0x3..". hex on AVR8535

Tags: vb.net, serial-port, avr

I have a problem with VB.Net serialport.Write() function, looks like the code sent from it was "prefixed" with 0x3.. so, when I'm trying to send "1" it will show on LED 00110001 or 0x31, then "2" will show 00110010.

```
serialport.Open()
serialport.Write(1)
```

though the AVR code below show what it received:

```
while(1)
{
    while(!ucsra.7)
    {
        data=UDR;
        PORTC=data;
        PORTB=data;
    }
}
```

which shows correct value when I send from CvAVR terminal

so, if anyone know what's wrong with it please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's happening because you're writing `String` values on serial port, for example `1` in [ASCII Table](http://www.asciitable.com/) is equal to `0x31`, I believe it explains the symptom.

To fix this problem you should send your data as `Byte` value, Here I cast my string to Byte for demonstration.

```
    Dim v = "1"
    Dim buffer(0) As Byte
    buffer(0) = CByte(v)

    serialport.Write(buffer, 0, 1)
```

Comment: that's explain my silly but yet fatal fault, but i still found trouble, even i casted it with Cbyte, it looks like still received ascii, or maybe the avr translate it into ascii, is there any other way to prevent this?

Comment: @ComeradEkaRamdhanHidayat my bad, I updated the answer, sorry for inconvenience